# Error: noclassdeffounderror in jar execution

Tags: spring, jar, manifest, executable-jar

I'm creating a desktop application using swing and spring for some stuffs. Everything is going very good but when I create the jar using eclipse JUNO I got this error trying to run it as *java -jar myjar.jar* on cmd. I don't know where is the problem, any help?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
        at efact.alfa1lab.nazca.jframe.NazcaLogin.<init>(NazcaLogin.java:145)
        at efact.alfa1lab.nazca.jframe.NazcaLogin$1.run(NazcaLogin.java:97)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
```

This is my folder structure

```
 - myclasses
 - images
 - lib
 - META-INF
 + MANIFEST.MF
   - applicationContext.xml
 - build.xml
```

This is my **MANIFEST.MF** with all spring jars, included: *spring-context-support-3.2.0.M1.jar* and *spring-context-3.2.0.M1.jar*

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/swingx-1.6.1.jar lib/spring-aop-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-context-support-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-context-3.2.0.M1.jar
  lib/javadbf-0.4.0.jar lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar lib/spring-asm-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-beans-3.2.0.M1.jar  
  lib/spring-core-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-expression-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-orm-3.2.0.M1.jar
  lib/spring-oxm-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-test-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-tx-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-web-3.2.0.M1.jar
  lib/spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-webmvc-3.2.0.M1.jar lib/spring-ws-1.5.9-all.jar lib/troughoasis.jar 
  lib/commons-lang-2.3.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/concar.jar lib/ini4j-0.5.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
Main-Class: com.mycompany.MainClass
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Class-Path` directive in `MANIFEST.MF` does not work as expected. I suggest you use [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/version-0.95/) in combination with Ant or Maven to package your application and all its dependencies into a single JAR. I've been using this approach for God knows how long - works flawlessly.